# Docker issues with Chef Container: "Not Found" error

Tags: docker, chef, knife

I recently tried out the Chef Docker container at: https://hub.docker.com/r/chef/chef/

I downloaded it and ran the container using the following commands:

> docker pull "chef/chef:12.19.33"
>   docker run -i -t --name test1 chef/chef:12.19.33

Inside the container, none of the Chef/Knife binaries work. The error says "not found". This is strange. Here is an example of the commands I used:

> / # ls -ltr /opt/chef/bin/knife
>   -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1599 Feb 16 19:28 /opt/chef/bin/knife
>   / # /opt/chef/bin/knife
>   sh: /opt/chef/bin/knife: not found

Does anyone know what is going on? I tried older Chef containers and still got the same issue. I also tried running Docker on other machines.

Answer (score 0):

This Docker image is supposed to be used as a data volume container, like with kitchen-dokken (https://github.com/someara/kitchen-dokken), instead of used solely by itself.